# Differences between android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar and Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-theme

When I use the following style

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

I get error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.xx.xx/com.xx.xx.setup.SetupASelectLanguageActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException

When I change it to:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

It gives no error.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

The Theme
**android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar**. Is OS dependent

While the appcompat version is explicitly added to your apk .
Also if you are using AppcompatActivity it would be better to use 
**Appcompat theme** it will avoid conflicts.